# Setting up permanent extra audio sinks/sources for streaming purposes?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, streaming, pipewire

So I have been on this for about a month now, and I've tried a dozen different ways of optimizing/automating the process. Basically want to be able to have something setup akin to that of [Voicemeeter](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/index.htm) (windows), but in Linux (arch).

My current workaround is the following pactl commands running at startup:

```
    { path = "pactl"        args = "load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Virtual1" }
    { path = "pactl"        args = "load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Virtual2" }
    { path = "pactl"        args = "load-module module-loopback sink=Virtual1" }
    { path = "pactl"        args = "load-module module-loopback sink=Virtual1" }
    { path = "pactl"        args = "load-module module-loopback sink=Virtual1" }
```

following which, I manually reroute [specific channels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c1Zw.png) in pavucontrol. But every now and then (especially post suspend) the routing is reset to something completely random and I have to go back into pavucontrol and make the necessary changes (specifically in the playback tab). The loading order of the loopback modules are also scrambled at times furthering adding to confusion in the manual tasks I have to perform every time I turn on my system.

My requirement is to combine mic and application audio to then send it via the mic (example: discord).

Is there any way to keep the sinks and sources not reset them on every boot/newly assign them each time? Or perhaps a way to automate the process of rerouting the channels such that they go exactly where I need them (virtual streams at least)?

Answer (score 1):

I've been having similar problem. Even if I have a script that sets up these sinks upon login, actually saving the wire route doesn't seem to be implemented in the tools such as `helvum` as of yet. The wiki does provide with a couple of scripts to handle that for you though:
`pw-savewires`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$#" -ne 1 ]]; then
    echo
    echo 'usage: pw-savewires filename'
    echo
    exit 0
fi

rm $1 &> /dev/null
while IFS= read -r line; do
    link_on=`echo $line | cut -f 4 -d '"'`
    link_op=`echo $line | cut -f 6 -d '"'`
    link_in=`echo $line | cut -f 8 -d '"'`
    link_ip=`echo $line | cut -f 10 -d '"'`
    echo "Saving: " "'"$link_on:$link_op"','"$link_in:$link_ip"'"
    echo "'"$link_on:$link_op"','"$link_in:$link_ip"'" >> $1
done < <(pw-cli dump short link)
```

when given filename for parameter, it will read your current wire connections and save them to a file: `pw-savewires foo` creates file named `foo`

Another script called pw-restore can be used to restore these wires:
`pw-loadwires`

```
#!/bin/python

import sys
import csv
import os

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('\n usage: pw-loadwires filename\n')
    quit()

with open(sys.argv[1], newline='') as csvfile:
    pwwreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in pwwreader:
        print('Loading:  ' + row[0] + ' --> ' + row[1])
        process = os.popen('pw-link ' + row[0] + ' ' + row[1])
```

so `pw-loadwires foo` should restore the wire configuration saved in file `foo`.
Hopefuly that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For discord specifically you can fully enable application audio in screenshare if you care to spend the effort setting it up, here is a guide on github:
https://github.com/edisionnano/Screenshare-with-audio-on-Discord-with-Linux
As for your more general question, I am also interested in an answer.  If you are using pipewire in your current setup, you may find helvum to be useful as a gui patchbay.  A friend of mine used qjackctl as a gui patchbay for a while which can save and load configurations as well, but uses jack as an interface to pipewire.